# How to make an image resize dynamically as the DIV changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where i need to set an image in the background of `<div>` and want it to resize according to the div dynamically. That means the height and width of the `<div>` can change according to the data on fly. So i want the image to follow the `<div>`.
thanks

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: that's not working

Comment: Are you using an `<img>` or a background image for the div?

Comment: background image for div

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks :this is how currently my div looks like: <div style="background-image: url(images/searchBackground.PNG); height: 150px; width: 1276px;background-repeat: no-repeat;"> </div>

Answer (score 2):

You could rely on the CSS background-size property. [See this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) - they apply it to the body element, but this could work with any `<div>`. Basically, it would look like this:

```
.examplediv {
background: url(images/example.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
 }
```

There are some filters that need to be applied to get IE to behave, but they are mentioned at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Resize images using jQuery** 
http://adeelejaz.com/blog/resize-images-on-fly-using-jquery/

```
var max_size = 200; 
$("img").each(function(i) { 
  if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) { 
    var h = max_size;   
    var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * max_size);   
  } else {  
    var w = max_size;   
    var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * max_size);   
  } 
  $(this).css({ height: h, width: w }); 
});
```

Comment: Yikes.. that's over 3 years old. I would hope no one does that anymore. Simple CSS for that solution: `img {width:auto; height:auto; max-width:200px; max-height:200px;}`

Comment: @rgthree: Post an answer.  Others are providing clues, but not any real answers.  Code doesn't get rusty, like a nail; if it works, it works.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I would reply, but chipcullen has the right answer (the question was about CSS-applied background images). Anyway, just lending a hand to avoid unnecessary overhead using javascript when browsers can natively handle this with CSS. A lot happens in 3 years to make things better and faster. No doubt your answer works, just not the best way any longer, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

set the width attribute in your image tag to 100%, so it will completely reside in the parent tag.

Comment: thats not wroking, this is what I am doing: <div style="background-image: url(images/searchBackground.PNG); height: 150px; width: 1276px;background-repeat: no-repeat;"> </div>......so it like it part of <div> properties

Comment: I think If you put the image tag inside the div tag then It may work like this    <div><img style="width:100%" src="..."></div>